# Skip lines while reading csv - Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from **Blob** to **Azure SQL** using **data flows** within a pipeline.
Data Files is in **csv** format and the **Header is at 4th row** in the csv file.
i want to use the header as is what is available in the csv data file.

I want to **loop** through all the files and upload data.

Thanks

Comment: Per my experience, I'm afraid we can do that.

Comment: Do you need the 3 rows above the Header?

Comment: Don't use Skip Lines. You'll lose the first 3 rows. Add a row counter (Surrogate Key or Window w/RowNumber) and then filter out the header row using Filter transform.

Comment: I have a csv which have 5 extra rows then header is in 6th row. so to read this file i have to skip 5 lines first and then use 6th row as header. and this is where i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Surrogate Key transformation and then a Filter transformation to filter out row number 4.

Comment: Assuming i am puling this csv file, it will take column 1... column 2 and ...n.
at this time field name has been decided already.
i want to skip 5 lines and use the 6th line as header for the csv.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first uncheck the "First row as header" in your CSV dataset. Then you can use the "Skip line count" field in the copy data activity source tab and skip any number of lines you want.